# Custom PowerShell cmdlet with a ScriptBlock in a hashtable

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, scriptblock

I have a custom Powershell Cmdlet in C#, all works fine.

The one parameter is a `HashTable`. How can I use a `ScriptBlock` in that parameter? When I set the parameter to `@{file={$_.Identity}}`, I want to get a pipeline object with `Identity` property in the `ProcessRecord` method. How can I do that?

Now I simple convert the keys/values of the hash table to `Dictionary<string, string>`, but  I want to get a pipelined object property (string).

Now I get an error that `ScriptBlock` can't convert to string.

Comment: Is this for Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core (6+)?

Comment: Windows PowerShell. I'll try convert with checking ScriptBlock type value:
var result = ScriptBlock.Create("{$_.Identity}").Invoke(pipelineobject); 
But result is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ForEach-Object` for this:

```
function Invoke-WithUnderScore {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [object[]]$InputObject,
    [scriptblock]$Property
  )

  process {
    $InputObject |ForEach-Object $Property
  }
}
```

Then use like:

```
PS C:\> "Hello","World!","This is a longer string" |Invoke-WithUnderscore -Property {$_.Length}
5
6
23
```

---

Or in a C# cmdlet:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Select, "Stuff")]
public class SelectStuffCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public object[] InputObject;

    [Parameter()]
    public Hashtable Property;

    private List<string> _files;

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        string fileValue = string.Empty;
        foreach (var obj in InputObject)
        {
            if (!Property.ContainsKey("file"))
                continue;

            if (Property["file"] is ScriptBlock)
            {
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2()))
                {
                    var result = ps.AddCommand("ForEach-Object").AddParameter("process", Property["file"]).Invoke(new[] { obj });
                    if (result.Count > 0)
                    {
                        fileValue = result[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fileValue = Property["file"].ToString();
            }

            _files.Add(fileValue);
        }
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        // process _files
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using PowerShell script, I have C# custom Cmdlet with override ProcessRecord()

Comment: I have two commandlets and want transfer from first to second.
I can transfer pipeline wole object, but I need only one of property. And using @{file={$_.Identity}} hashtable to transfer one of property to second cmdlet.

Comment: @АлексейУсталов Then call `ForEach-Object` from C#: `ps.AddCommand("ForEach-Object").AddParameter("Process",$scriptblock).Invoke(inputobjects);`

Comment: I'm not understand how I put ForEach-Object result to my hashtable?

Comment: I'm try invoke:
RunspaceInvoke runspace = new RunspaceInvoke();
var result = runspace.Invoke("ForEach-Object {$_.Identity}", new[] { obj });
but got 'null'